# jQuery multidimensional object array coming up undefined

Tags: jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I'm bringing an array into jquery from php, on a wordpress website. It is a multidimensional array that looks like this after I convert into $jqueryArray (taken from console.log)

2 : Object { max=" 10", min=" 500 ", number=" 2 "}

3 : Object { max=" 15", min=" 750 ", number=" 3 "}

4 : Object { max=" 8", min=" 400 ", number=" 4 "}

5 : Object { max=" 12", min=" 700 ", number=" 5 "}

1 : Object { max=" 10", min=" 500 ", number="1 "}

The code is as follows:

```
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.wpsc_select_variation').change(function(){

        var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($alt_tables) ?>;
        var $jqueryArray = {};

            jQuery.each(arrayFromPHP, function (key, value) {
                $jqueryArray[key] = {};
                $jqueryArray[key] = value;
            });
        console.log($jqueryArray);

        // clears the div that we will type the Table Minimum order too
        jQuery('#table-details').empty();
        var $selectedName;

        // returns an integer, specific to the Table # selected
        $selectedName = jQuery(this).find(':selected').text().replace('Table ', '');

        console.log($jqueryArray.$selectedName);

        var $newDetails = 'Table minimum order: ';
        jQuery('#table-details').append( $newDetails );
    });

});
```

For some reason $jqueryArray.$selectedName is undefined. I can see that $jqueryArray has 5 keys, numbered 1 through 5, but even when i try console.log($jqueryArray.1); I get undefined. I can't seem to figure out how to call the number from the array. Basically I want

$jqueryArray[$selectedName][min]
I've tried $jqueryArray[$selectedName] in the console.log and receive undefined as well

I added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzuyd/14/

I took the `<?php echo json_encode($alt_tables) ?>` and just added it as the variable, since php doesn't work in jsfiddle. Hopefully it works the same..

Comment: You're not adding `$selectedName` to `$jqueryArray`...

Comment: How would I do that? $selectedName is an integer, like 1 or 2, and $jqueryArray has integers 1 through 5 as keys

Comment: I've tried console.log($jqueryArray["1"]); and console.log($jqueryArray[1]); and both return undefined

Comment: Post a jsfiddle if possible it would be helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kzuyd/14/

Comment: But your `$selectedName` contains `Table4` (if you select that) so how do you want to find anything in your array as there is no such key in there?

Comment: p.s. In javascript code using the jQuery lib, the convention of prefixing a variable with `$` is usually reserved for jQuery objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kzuyd/15/)

```
jQuery(function() {
    var arrayFromPHP = '{"1 ":{"note":null,"max":" 10","min":" 500 ","number":"1 "}," 2 ":{"note":null,"max":" 10","min":" 500 ","number":" 2 "}," 3 ":{"note":null,"max":" 15","min":" 750 ","number":" 3 "}," 4 ":{"note":null,"max":" 8","min":" 400 ","number":" 4 "}," 5 ":{"note":null,"max":" 12","min":" 700 ","number":" 5 "}}';

    var $jqueryArray = {};

    // you must parse `arrayFromPHP`, it's not actually an array now
    // it's a JSON string
    jQuery.each(JSON.parse(arrayFromPHP), function(key, value) {

        // your keys have spaces at the end of them e.g. "1 "
        // trim them first
        $jqueryArray['Table' + key.trim()] = {};
        $jqueryArray['Table' + key.trim()] = value;
    });

    jQuery('.wpsc_select_variation').change(function() {

        jQuery('#table-details').empty();
        jQuery('#table-minimum').empty();
        var $selectedName;

        $selectedName = jQuery(this)
            .find("option:selected")
            .text()
            .replace(/\s/g, '');
            // to replace all spaces, use the regex shown

        var $newDetails = 'The selected name: ' + $selectedName + '';
        jQuery('#table-details').append($newDetails);

        // use obj["min"] to get the minimum
        var $tableMin = '<br /><br />The table minimum is: ' +
                        $jqueryArray[$selectedName]["min"] + '';
        jQuery('#table-minimum').append($tableMin);
    });

});​
```

Comment: Was the issue the fact that some variables had extra spaces hanging around? Regardless, thank you for the help!! I have spent hours on this

Comment: There were a couple of issues, mainly the ones I commented in my code above. If I had to blame one issue though it would be your `.each()` loop, since your 'array' variable is actually just a string, it [iterates over its characters instead](http://jsfiddle.net/kzuyd/17/).

Comment: That issue was only in the fiddle. The original code was var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($alt_tables) ?>; but I couldn't bring that into the fiddle directly. Glad you noticed it and fixed it, thanks again!